# Spring Rest Controller skip method argument validation in unit test

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have configured Spring to validate controller method arguments, by adding `MethodValidationPostProcessor` bean in application configuration, and adding `@validated` annotation on controller.

```
public Entity getEntity(@MyConstraint @RequestParam  int limit)
```

`MyConstraint` validation is applied in application, but when running unit test, validation is not triggered.

Test class looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class ControllerTest {
    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setControllerAdvice(new ControllerExceptionHandler())
                        .build();
    }
    @Test
    public void testCase() throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc.perform(get("locale?limit=-1")).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
```

Any idea what is wrong with my test?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that context scanning isn't being done by the unit test, but it is for the app.

Comment: How are you actually testing this? Direct call or through MockMVC?

Comment: @M. Denium I am testing through MockMVC: mockMvc.perform(get( "url?value=-1")).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

Comment: Please add your full test case not only the header.

Comment: @M. Denium Here is full test case. I removed some test cases that are not important: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
`@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class TranslationLocaleControllerTest
{
     @Test
    public void testGetLocalesNonHateoasNegativeLimit() throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc.perform(get( "locale?limit=-1")).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }`

Comment: Please don't add additional code as comments , edit your question instead.

Comment: Done. Thanks for advice.

Comment: @M. Deinum Have you got any idea, or any hint? I am still blocked with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: You are using the `standaloneSetup` which doesn't take into account what is in your context. Use the `MockMvcBuilder.webAppContextSetup` instead.

Comment: @M. Deinum I tried with webAppcontextSetup but I have different problems. I oppened a new issue #34316608. But I'd rather prefer to configure the standalone setup context to do the same things. Much appreciated.

Comment: That isn't going to work as the standalone setup only does a setup with default settings for your case and doesn't honor your other configuration options. If you get other issues fix those instead of trying to make a way work that isn't intended as such.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add @WebAppConfiguration annotation to your Test Class.

Comment: I have added @webappconfiguration but same result `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class) I am quite new to spring boot. So I might have made newbie  mistakes. `